# Read plaintext document into NSArray in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS but have plenty of experience with c++ and Python. I'm trying to figure out how to read a plaintext file I have on my computer into an NSArray in xcode. In c++ I would do this:

```
while(istr>>string) myArray.push_back(string);
```

However, I need to create a local copy to be stored on the iOS device. Is there a way I can package this data so that a local copy of JUST THE ARRAY will be stored on the device? I was thinking of maybe doing something with a JSON serialization or something. 
Should I really just suck it up and do this:

```
NSArray myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"myInfo", nil];
```

I just want a more elegant way to handle this, I guess.

Comment: what exactly do you want to store in your array? A string of the plaintext?

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe you're thinking a little too C about this. In C and C++, strings are arrays of bytes. In ObjC, there's an object for that. It's called NSString, and it's probably what you should be storing plaintext in.

It even has an easy class method to help you out with this if you already  have a byte array:

`+(id)stringWithCString:(const char *)cString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc`

See the [NSString documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for more details.

As to storing it on the device, there are solutions that  range from the simple ([`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) to the complex ([Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html)), but pretty much anything will expect plain text be in an `NSString`.

**EDIT:**
The title of this question talks about reading the string from the filesystem. First step is to get the bytes of the file into an [`NSData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object. The easy way:

`+(id)dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path`

Then make a string out of the data with this initializer of `NSString`:

`-(id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you, anyway if you just need to store an array of data to filesystem and deserialize it back to NSArray, an easy way is to use plists. 
It is a convenient way to store a small amount of data, without any kind of relationship (there is Core Data for that). The main advantage is that you can store in it NSArray, NSDictionary, NSNumber, NSString, NSDate and NSData (so any kind of binary information) and they get automatically serialized and deserialized through some simple methods.

You can write an NSArray to a file in this way:

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

and deserialize it back with this:

```
+ (id)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
```

If you just want to provide some initial data to your app, and it is for example an array of strings or something similar, you can manually add a plist to your project by going to File->New->File and choosing Resources->Property list, and fill it by hand.

You can read more at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html